# SQL - Insert Into Select (multiple columns)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

front end web guy thrown into the SQL abyss. Below is a prototype of our current SQL query:

```
 INSERT INTO table (table column)
 SELECT ad.val1, web.val2, ad.val3
 FROM ad
 LEFT JOIN web
 ON ad.val 4 = web.val4
```

We've recently added a web.val5 column and we want to insert it's information to the same column as web.val4

I tried the following using the ALL clause:

```
 INSERT INTO table (table column)
 SELECT ad.val1, web.val2, ad.val3
 FROM ad
 LEFT JOIN web
 ON ad.val 4 = web.val4   
 AND ad.val4 = web.val5
```

But I keep getting 0 (or NULL?). Is there a certain clause that I can add to a LEFT JOIN that can equate a value to two different values in different columns within the same table? Sorry if this is confusing, I barely understand it myself.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You can consider joining it twice and match that condition like

```
 INSERT INTO table (table column)
 SELECT ad.val1, web.val2, ad.val3
 FROM ad
 LEFT JOIN web
 ON ad.val4 = web.val4  
 LEFT JOIN web w           //second join
 ON ad.val4 = w.val5
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing a little bit here, but if I understand your issue, your `and` criteria is making it return the `null` values.  Instead you want `or` or `in`:

```
INSERT INTO table (table column)
SELECT ad.val1, web.val2, ad.val3
FROM ad
    LEFT JOIN web ON ad.val4 IN (web.val4, web.val5)
```